# how to play a mediaStream object in javascript

Tags: mediastream

i have a mediaStream object from a webrtc peer, and would like to play it. Im sending the stream from the other end from an online source e.g "http://songs.ca/track1.mp3" I get this MediaStream Object:

```
MediaStream { id: "{3ac77543-657a-4b31-a490-8e6811d96fec}", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null }
​
active: true
​
id: "{3ac77543-657a-4b31-a490-8e6811d96fec}"
​
onaddtrack: null
​
onremovetrack: null
​
<prototype>: MediaStreamPrototype { getAudioTracks: getAudioTracks(), getVideoTracks: getVideoTracks(), getTracks: getTracks(), … }
​​
active: 
​​
addTrack: function addTrack()
​​
clone: function clone()
​​
constructor: function ()
​​
getAudioTracks: function getAudioTracks()
​​
getTrackById: function getTrackById()
​​
getTracks: function getTracks()
​​
getVideoTracks: function getVideoTracks()
​​
id: 
​​
onaddtrack: 
​​
onremovetrack: 
​​
removeTrack: function removeTrack()
​​
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "MediaStream"
​​
<get active()>: function active()
​​
<get id()>: function id()
​​
<get onaddtrack()>: function onaddtrack()
​​
<set onaddtrack()>: function onaddtrack()
​​
<get onremovetrack()>: function onremovetrack()
​​
<set onremovetrack()>: function onremovetrack()
​​
<prototype>: EventTargetPrototype { addEventListener: addEventListener(), removeEventListener: removeEventListener(), dispatchEvent: dispatchEvent(), … }
```

how can I listen to audio from this?

I cant seem to play this media stream,
I've isolated the code to just produce a media stream and play it

```
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var ans = "http://live.hbstreaming.com:2370/stream"
document.getElementById("plyaudi").setAttribute('src', `${ans}`);
const audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
const track = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
var destination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination()
track.connect(destination);
console.log(destination.stream)

const playButton = document.querySelector('.btn');

playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (audioCtx.state === 'suspended') {
        audioCtx.resume();
    }
    
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.autoplay = true;
    audio.srcObject = destination.stream
}, false);
```

it still doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

You can create an [`audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element and assign your `MediaStream` as the `srcObject`. There are several ways to do this; here is one example:

```js
const audio = new Audio();
audio.autoplay = true;
audio.srcObject = mediaStream;
```

Comment: I have tried this but i still dont seem to get any sound. So now im just creating locally the mediaStream object. still doesnt work.  This is what im doing atm. I'vw updated in the question

Comment: What is the "playaudi" element supposed to be? I don't see you actually referencing the source anywhere except that call on the "plyaudi" element, and it is unclear to me what that is.

Here is a simplistic example that works for me locally as a potential starting point: https://gist.github.com/lizadaily/75b78a17f55d570ff08fb0158c60e88a
`

Comment: "playaudi" is the html <audio> element id. In the webrtc code from google codelabs, i was trying to assign the url src to this element so i can play it. i can normally hear the sound using media stream using the audio.srcObject = mediaStream when im using the mic from getusermedia. But since My source is a url, i replaced the getusermedia with the webaudio api as seen above. so with this i cant hear the audio.